# Access a list within a dict in request.POST

Tags: django, django-views

In my html I am dynamically generating drop-down options with the same name

```
<form action="{% url manageCsv %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="doc_id" value="{{ doc_id }}">
        {% for column in file_columns %}
        Column {{ forloop.counter0|add:1 }}
        <select name="columns">
            <option value="blank"></option>
            {% for column_value in file_columns %}
            <option value="{{ column_value }}">{{ column_value }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

**UPDATE:**
My Views.py :

```
def manageCsv(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_id = request.POST['doc_id']
        csvColumns = request.POST['columns']

        print >> sys.stderr, csvColumns['columns']

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

In my view when I print my request.POST I get everythin I need :

```
 <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'lGlxVmiYI9xFb5bV7cJPrP9GR0t0LYTi'], u'doc_id': [u'14'], u'columns': [u'Organisation', u'Sum of products']}>
```

But the problem I am facing is that when I assign `csvColumns = request.POST['columns']` , `csvColumns` prints out **only** `Sum of products` from the list and not the entire List `[u'Organisation', u'Sum of products']`

How can I get the entire list ? What have I missed ?

Any help on this would be great

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the model(s) and view that feed into this please?

Comment: Please write down you view.py files, that can help us,

Comment: Update the question with my views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it like this as explained in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict):

```
csvColumns = request.POST.getlist('columns',None)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thats sweet, works fine, i got it to work, doing something like `csvColumns = json.loads(json.dumps(request.POST))` , will use your way. Thanks